# Calculating the percentage of values based on the values in other columns

Tags: python

I am trying to create a column that includes a percentage of values based on the values in other columns in python. For example, let's assume that we have the following dataset.

```
+------------------------------------+------------+--------+
|              Teacher               |  grades    | counts |
+------------------------------------+------------+--------+
| Teacher1                           |     1      |    1   |
|                                    |     2      |    2   |
|                                    |     3      |    1   |
| Teacher2                           |     2      |    1   |
| Teacher3                           |     3      |    2   |
| Teacher4                           |     2      |    2   |
|                                    |     3      |    2   |
+------------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

As you can see we have teachers in the first columns, grades that teacher gives (1,2 and 3) in the second column, and the number of given corresponding grade in third columns. Here, I am trying to get the percentage of grade numbers 1 and 2 in total given grade for each teacher. For instance, teacher 1 gave one grade 1, two grade 2, and one grade 3. In this case, the percentage of given grade numbers 1 and 2 in the total grade is 75%. Teacher 2 gave only 1 grade 2 so the percentage is 100%. Similarly, teacher 3 gave two grade 3 so the percentage 0% because he/she did not give any grades 1 and 2. So these percentages should be added to the new column in the dataset. Honestly, I couldn't even think about anything to try and I didn't find anything about it when I search it in here. Could you please help me to get the column.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the most efficient way, but I find it quite readable and easy to follow.

```
percents = {} #store Teacher:percent
for t, g in df.groupby('Teacher'): #t,g is short for teacher,group
    total = g.counts.sum()
    one_two = g.loc[g.grades.isin([1,2])].counts.sum() #consider only 1&2
    percent = (one_two/total)*100
    #print(t, percent)
    percents[t] = [percent]
    
xf = pd.DataFrame(percents).T.reset_index() #make a df from the dic
xf.columns = ['Teacher','percent'] #rename columns
df = df.merge(xf) #merge with initial df

print(df)

    Teacher  grades  counts  percent
0  Teacher1       1       1     75.0
1  Teacher1       2       2     75.0
2  Teacher1       3       1     75.0
3  Teacher2       2       1    100.0
4  Teacher3       3       2      0.0
5  Teacher4       2       2     50.0
6  Teacher4       3       2     50.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will solve your query

```
y=0
data['Percentage']='None'
for teacher in teachers:
    x=data[data['Teachers']==teacher]
    total=sum(x['Counts'])
    condition1= 1 in set(x['Grades'])
    condition2= 2 in set(x['Grades'])
    if (condition1==True or condition2==True):
        for i in range(y,y+len(x)):
            data['Percentage'].iloc[i]=(data['Counts'].iloc[i]/total)*100          
    else:
        for i in range(y,y+len(x)):
            data['Percentage'].iloc[i]=0
    y=y+len(x)

Output:
    Teachers    Grades  Counts  Percentage
0   Teacher1    1          1    25
1   Teacher1    2          2    50
2   Teacher1    3          1    25
3   Teacher2    2          1    100
4   Teacher3    3          2    0
5   Teacher4    2          2    50
6   Teacher4    3          2    50
```

I have made used of boolean comprehension to segregate the data on
basis on each teacher. Most of the code is self explanatory. For any
other clarification please fill free to leave a comment.